# How to scale UIImageView when device is rotated?

Tags: ios, uiimageview

I want that my UIImageView becomes fullscreen when I rotate the device. How can I do that?

Comment: If it was full screen before and you want to keep it that way, set your autosizing mask accordingly (you can do that with either the `autoresizingMask` or in Interface Builder). If it wasn't, you can change it's frame in the `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation` or in iOS 5+ in `viewWillLayoutSubviews`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implement `willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:...` in your view controller and set the desired frame for the image view, depending on the orientation:

```
- (void)willAnimateRotationToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation duration:(NSTimeInterval)duration
{
    if (UIInterfaceOrientationIsLandscape(toInterfaceOrientation) {
         self.imageView.frame = ...
    } else {
         self.imageView.frame = ...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

And don't forget to set your `autoresizingMask` to something like that:

```
self.imageView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
```

If you do it like that, you don't have to care about the frame adjustment yourself.

cheers

Answer (score -1):

set the uiimageview.frame equal to widow.view.frame,and choose scale to fit mode